# Who are these cartoon characters?

Tags: knowledge, visual

Who are these wacky frienemies?

[image: Wacky hijinks in the skies]

(The puzzle is the image, all words to state the task/question are strenuously connected to the answer at best)

Hint

> They are derived from logotypes for something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rabbit is

> Microsoft Azure
>  The head corresponds to the whitespace in the middle of the logo
>  [image]

The child is

> Google Cloud
>  Again, the head corresponds to the whitespace in the middle of the logo
>  [image]

The background image

> is to hint at "cloud computing".

Comment: Nice, except rot13(whfg gur abezny nmher ybtb svgf orggre va obgu funcr naq zrnavat)

Comment: @SteveV Yes, you're right, thanks. I've changed it now.

Comment: Good work in figuring these out :)